# Unity3d. How to find detect incorrect convex mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote mesh generator for `MeshCollider`. But sometimes, when I set convex property to `ture`, some errors happened to appear the log.

For example, now I have a Mesh with 44 vertices and this errors:

> > CreateTrianglesFromPolygons: convex hull has a polygon with less than 3 vertices!

or

> > convex hull init failed! Try to use the PxConvexFlag::eINFLATE_CONVEX flag.

or something else...

**All I want**, is to detect and handle this error. But `try catch` do not work:

```
try
{
    collider.convex = true;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success! TrCount: " + collider.sharedMesh.triangles.Length.ToString()); // "Success! TrCount: 84"
}
catch
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error occur"); // never appear
}
```

Maybe there are some rules to detect it before setting convex to true.

Thank you for any help ).

Comment: Why are you using a **mesh collider** ?  You never, ever, use mesh colliders.

Comment: Having the same issue, and below answer suggestions similarly don't work for me (triangles.Length is over 100). Did you find any solution for this yet?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen, I used mesh cutter to cut mesh and sometimes I end up with all vertices in one plane. So I added a check to check distance of each vertex to the cutting plane, and if maximum distance is smaller than 0.001f, I rejected this mesh. It solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `catch(ExceptionType)`

```
try
{
    collider.convex = true;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error occur: " + e.Message);
}
```

Include `using System;` at the top.

EDIT:

The error message is **NOT** an exception so the method below should solve your problem. Remember that convex requires the triangle to be < 255 to work. The code below makes sure that your trigs is between **3** and **254**.

```
if (generatedMesh.triangles.Length >= 3 && generatedMesh.triangles.Length < 255)
{
    collider.convex = true;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success!");
}else
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error occur: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: No. Do not work. The `collider.convex = true;` do not throw any exception! But I want to not if error occur

Comment: @StasBZ Updated my answer after I realized that this is not exception.

Comment: Do not work. sharedMesh.triangles.Length == 84. See my updated question.

Comment: @StasBZ Your update does not make sense. Try what I have in my updated script `if (generatedMesh.triangles.Length >= 3 && generatedMesh.triangles.Length < 255)
{
    collider.convex = true;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success!");
}else
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error occur");
}`  Try that. It should work. Forget about the exception in your code

Comment: Okay, I did. But still do not work, the condition is true because triangles.Length == 84 and this error `convex hull has a polygon with less than 3 vertices!`

Comment: If you are interested you can see my saved mesh [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7JuXRQLq2gnOVFDdTRmZWNqRUU/view?usp=sharing). I need a way to predict such problem mesh before an error occur